# What's the right way to look up message keys in mailgun?

Tags: mailgun

We recently received notification from mailgun that they no longer want us calling their server to delete individual messages. Instead they will simply delete Emails older than 3 days. When our server is restarted for releases, we need to check for undelivered messages that came through while we were down. What message key do we use?

I think we should do this:

1. Call https://api.mailgun.net/v3/OUR_DOMAIN/events, which returns
   something like:

```
    {
        items: [{
            storage: {
                url: "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/domains/chat-dev.mormon.org/messages/a120CharacterString",
                key: "a120CharacterString"
            }
            ...
            id: "4ifaf0AdRDicgteNUqDdWA"
        },
        ...
        ]
    }
```

2. Check our database for the item.storage.key.
3. If it's not there, make a call to the item.storage.url to get the
   message.

Is this right? There's also an item.id and an item.message.header.messageId that are much shorter, but these don't look like the right data to use.

Also, I'm assuming that the webhook signature should not be used to look up a message. Is that right?